# Query Column1 on the basis of Column2 of another table

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-like

I need something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Name LIKE %Table2.Name%
```

Comment: Can you post your specific table names, and the relevant fields from the tables (names and data types). Also include the fields you need for the join.

Answer (score 1):

```
select <col list>
from table1 t1 inner join table2 t2
on t1.name like concat('%', t2.name, '%')
```

Comment: you tagged your question as mysql, and I tried it on mysql successfully before posting. What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can use join between 2 tables if there is a common field.